# Print screen shortcut have a different save directory from gnome-screnshot

Tags: gnome, screenshot, dconf, gsettings, gnome-screenshot

After rebooting, the wallpaper are not loaded then I noticed that I accidentally moved the **~/Pictures** directory to another location. So I put it back.

But the screenshots are not saved to **~/Pictures** then I have run the command below to set the gnome-screenshot save location :

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory /home/myuser/Pictures
```

When I run `gnome-screenshot` the files are saved like expected to **~/Pictures**
But when using `Print` shortcut the images are saved on the home directory `~/`

How to reset `Print` shortcut save location to **~/Pictures** again ?

> Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks in advance.